# need signature sample on Windows-Mobile (paint)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I need a getting signature sample running on Windows-Mobile. (paint)

How to draw on Windows-Mobile on screen - and save the Picture?

Can I get sample code (C#) ?

Comment: @Gold: I modified the code in my linked answer to work with .Net CF (since it doesn't have Pens or MouseEventArgs.Location).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenNETCF has a signature control that does exactly this:  http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/e2ec2ece-e6f1-8e43-0f59-9270bf186c38.htm

**Update:**  If you don't want to use that signature control, here is an answer that shows how to draw on a `PictureBox` (technically, how to draw on a `Bitmap` set as the picture box's `Image` property):

[how to draw drawings in picture box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537090/how-to-draw-drawings-in-picture-box/1537208#1537208)

That code will work in Windows Mobile, also.  To save what you've drawn as a bitmap file, just do this:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(...);
```