# I want to draw a point in WinForm Picture Box use my method to draw

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pixel

I created a function of drawing the pixel
But I can not show it
i want to use my methode to draw point 
As in the following code

```
Imports System.Math
Public Class Form1

Private Sub myc(ByVal x1 As Integer, ByVal y1 As Integer, ByVal r As Integer, ByVal r2 As Integer, ByVal c As Double)
    Dim y, nx, ny As Integer
    Dim th As Double
    For th = 0 To 360 Step 1
        nx = x1 + r * Sin(th * 22 / 7 / 180)
        ny = y1 + r2 * Cos(th * 22 / 7 / 180)
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please do not add pictures of code. Write it out.

Comment: Edit your question!! Not a comment lol

Comment: Sorry
I am a new user does not use the site

Comment: What API are you using? WPF? WinForm? ASP.NET? Metro or whatever Microsoft is calling it now?

Comment: i'm using visual basic.net 2013-windows form

Comment: Consult [How to draw in picture box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537090/)?

Comment: But I want to use the previous function
I typed in the language vb6
It was a good
When used "picture1.pset(nx,yx)"
But in the language of vb.net
did not work
I think he wants to turn it into another format in order to show

Comment: Are you looking for equivalent of `Pset` in VB.Net?

Comment: VB6 and VB.NET are different languages, you cannot expect the same code to work in both. `PSet` is not going to work in VB.NET because you need to plot lines, not points. You also need to store your endpoints in a list or something and redraw them in the Form Paint event because Form picureboxes are not persisted. [How to draw in picture box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537090/)shows how to do both those things.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cir(ByVal x1 As Integer, ByVal y1 As Integer, ByVal r1 As Integer, ByVal r2 As Integer, ByVal c As Color)

        Dim pic As Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(1000, 1000)
        Dim th As Double
        Dim nx, ny As Integer

        For th = 0 To 360 Step 0.5

            nx = x1 + r1 * Cos(th * 22 / 7 / 180)
            ny = x1 + r2 * Sin(th * 22 / 7 / 180)
            pic.SetPixel(nx, ny, c)
            PictureBox1.Image = pic


        Next th

    End Sub



    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cir(100, 100, 50, 50, Color.Blue)


    End Sub
```